# C# How Can I Get Method Code via other method?

Tags: c#

I am wondering if it is possible to have two methods, and the second one to actually output the 1st one's body code content.

For example:

```
public void firstMethod(int input)
{
    input = 123;
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}


public void secondMethod()
{
   //Output the code of firstMethod
}
```

*The secondMethod should output exactly:

```
public void firstMethod(int input)
{
    input = 123;
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

Is there a way to do that using Mono.Cecil or somehow read the IL or Opcodes and then convert them back into C# syntax? Or perhaps direct code grab?

Comment: you can get the IL easily enough (`someMethodInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()`) - and you can use various tools to decompile it, but: you shouldn't ever expect that decompiled IL is *exactly* the same as the original source code - and if the method is obfuscated: it'll look *nothing* like it

Comment: If you could, what would this enable you to *do* with the result? I smell a faint whiff of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: How would you expect this to work if the code has been optimized? For example, the compiler might optimize the method so that it is just `Console.WriteLine(123);` and avoid the assignment altogether.